# Linux: What should I use to run terminal programs based on a calendar system?

Tags: linux, cron, terminal, remote-server

Sorry about the really ambiguous question, I really have no idea how to word it though hopefully I can give you more detail here.

I am developing a project where a user can log into a website and book a server to run a game for a specific amount of time. When the time is up the server stops running and the players on the server are kicked off. The website part is not a problem, I am doing this in PHP and everything works. It has a calendar system to book a server and can generate config files based on what the user wants.

My question is what should I use to run the specific game server on the linux box with those config files at the correct time? I have got this working with bash scripts and cron, but it seems very un-elegant. It literally uses FTP to connect to the website so it can download all the necessary config files and put them in a folder for that game and time. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. Perhaps writing a program in C, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

(I am not asking for someone to hold my hand and tell me "write this code here", just some ideas of a better way of approaching this problem)

Thanks so much guys!

Edit: The webserver is a totaly different machine. I would theoreticaly like to have more than one game server where each of them "connects" (at the moment FTP) to the webserver, gets a file saying what it has to do at a specific time and downloads any associated files then disconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [at](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) is better suited for running one time jobs than cron.

For a better approach for the downloading files etc, you should give more details on your setup (like, the website and the game server, are they on the same machine? Or the same network? etc etc.

Comment: The webserver is a totaly different machine. I would theoreticaly like to have more than one game server where each of them "connects" (at the moment FTP) to the webserver, gets a file saying what it has to do at a specific time and downloads any associated files then disconnects.

Comment: I just looked into "at" I do think that is a better way to run at a specific time. Though can I use a variable for the time? It needs to check if there is an update to the calandar every 5 minutes say, but it could potentialy be running a server at any time.

Comment: Well, you can tell it to run at a certain time. You could however parse the output of the `atq` command and remove, and reinsert it at a different time.

Comment: And the at page seems to refer to [nqs](http://www.chem.ucl.ac.uk/resources/history/people/clary/pubs/man/nqs.html) if you need more control over resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need a distributed task scheduler. With that, you can:

1. Schedule command "X" to be run at a certain time.
2. Specify the machine (or ask it to pick a machine from a pool of available machines)

Webserver would send request to this scheduler via command line or via web service when user selects a game server and a time.

You can have a look at : http://www.acelet.com/super/SuperWatchdog/index.html

EDIT :

One more option :http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/